# Type specificity in conditional type

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I'm trying to type properties of the React component in a way that when one of the properties has specific value then the type of the other property changes. Overall, I know how to do it if the input type is something like `string | number` but I don't know how to do it if it's `string | "specificString"`. Maybe it's not even possible?

Here are my two attempts to achieve that.

```
type Action = "createItem" | "updateItem" | "deleteItem";

type Props<TName = string> = {
    name: TName;
    value: TName extends "_action" ? Action : string;
};

const props: Props = {
    name: "_action",
    value: "wrongAction", // I want it to error
};
```

Second try:

```
type Action = "createItem" | "updateItem" | "deleteItem";

type Props = {
    name: "_action";
    value: Action;
} | {
    name: string;
    value: string;
};

const props: Props = {
    name: "_action",
    value: "wrongAction", // I want it to error
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHZQLxQERwE4QCGwEAkiQLbZQA+OArmACbFmXV3ZMQA2EJ5CFQDcAKFEB6CVAC0c+QvGhIUAAp5kYAM4wAPABUAcoQrQsW4HkSoA5gD5MUAN6iobqKhMQAXFCNexdygAN0Ieeh8-Y1MoCAAPElQmLRwAfUIEFFRqAH5YTLQoXwsrWzEAXzFRODQLKDANbRhfdU0dRxcgz1NfbHSC7IAaV3dQ8MjsAHcNW3gkNGxBqCkoUihJwlRgKERt4GRYvA08UUrxFYVLmSVwaFbtACEOkbduif757MDRsIjfOayFVozheHi8xUs1hs3zcYz+UBKUIqVRqqDqDTaDxajS0TywnXcb16Hyyi1BcIm0zQNgBCyWKzWGy2Oz2BwgR2QJzOQA)

Any ideas how to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: a standalone `type` will not work in this case. As you said `string | "_action"` will will result in `string`. But a generic type in combination with a function can do this validation. Would [this](https://tsplay.dev/weXgXW) fit your needs? If yes, I could write up an answer

Comment: @TobiasS. hmmm interesting. So using an object instead of a single value and using `const` makes a difference. I guess it could work if it's not to be used as React component where I would have to write `<Component {...{name: "_action", value: "createItem"} as const} />` which is not great to have type safety. It would still not work with `<Component name="_action" value="createItem" />`. However, thank you for the explanation! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this example:

```js
import React from 'react'

type Action = "createItem" | "updateItem" | "deleteItem";

type ValidateProps<T> =
  /**
   * Check whether our argument has allowed type shape
   */
  T extends { name: infer A, value: infer V }
  /**
   * Check if [name] is "_action"
   */
  ? ('_action' extends A
    /**
     * If [name] is "_action" and [value] is Action
     */
    ? (V extends Action
      /**
       * Return T
       */
      ? T
      /**
       * Otherwise highlight wrong property
       */
      : { name: A, value: 'Error: [value] is not allowed' })
    : { name: A, value: V }
  )
  : never

type Props<Name, Value> = {
  name: Name,
  value: Value
}

const Foo = <
  Name extends string,
  Value extends string,
  >(props: ValidateProps<Props<Name, Value>>) => <div />

const allowed1 = <Foo name="_action" value="createItem" /> // ok
const allowed2 = <Foo name="anything" value="hello" /> // ok
const not_allowed = <Foo name="_action" value="hello" /> // expected error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nnaxew)

You need to infer literal type from `name` and `value` property and them validate it.

If you are interested in argument type inference, you can check my articles [here](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments) and [here](https://catchts.com/validators)

P.S. Feel free to use `never` instead of `'Error: [value] is not allowed'`. I just added it for the sake of readability

Comment: Wow nice, thank you! I have to say that at first glance it looked like super complex. After reading through the code, it makes sense but I would never come up with this solution :). I will definitely read your articles to dive deeper. Thank you!

Comment: It is true, TS types some time are unreadable, but it is just a set of nested conditional type, nothing more